# Decision Tree using data mining technique to determine whether a tumor is benign or malignant

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, data-mining, decision-tree

I have to read patient data from a .csv file and using a decision tree determine, based on the data being read in for each patient, whether the tumor is Benign or Malignant.

I am really struggling with how to even start this. So far I have written code that reads from the .csv file and stores the data into a vector as shown below spreading over a few header and cpp files.

From what I gather, I can create a parent decision class and then each attribute I am to process are the children classes. Not sure if that makes sense. Please let me know.

Below you will find the attributes I am to process along with a graphical tree that shows how it is determined whether the tumor is Benign or Malignant that I need to base my code off of. I will also include a small sample of the .csv file.

[image: These are the attributes that are included in the .csv file and how they are represented on a scale]

[image: This is the graphical decision tree that shows how a tumor is determines if it is Benign or Malignant. This is what I am to base my code off of.]

[image: This is the data collected in the .csv file. Each column is in the order of the attributes in the first image (the table) I have included above.]

Please could I get some guidance as how I am to do this. I am having the greatest difficulty with pointer notation. Any guidance will greatly be appreciated.

```
CSVLine.h
```

```
#ifndef CSVLINE_H
#define CSVLINE_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class CSVLine
{
private:
    vector<string> data;

public:
    CSVLine() {}
    CSVLine(const CSVLine& other)
    {
        data = other.data;
    }

    CSVLine operator = (const CSVLine& other)
    {
        data = other.data;
    }
    ~CSVLine() {}

    void parse(string line, char delimiter = ',');
    string getString(int columnNumber);
    int getInt(int columnNumber);
};

#endif
```

```
CSVLine.cpp
```

```
#include "CSVLine.h"

void CSVLine::parse(string line, char delimiter)
{
    stringstream inLine(line);

    string tempColumn = "";

    while (getline(inLine, tempColumn, delimiter))
    {
        data.push_back(tempColumn);
    }
}

string CSVLine::getString(int columnNumber)
{
    return data[columnNumber];
}

int CSVLine::getInt(int columnNumber)
{
    return atoi(data[columnNumber].c_str());
}
```

```
CSVReader.h
```

```
#ifndef CSVREADER_H
#define CSVREADER_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "CSVLine.h"

using namespace std;

class CSVReader
{
public:
    CSVReader() {}

    vector<CSVLine> read(string fileName);
};

#endif
```

```
CSVReader.cpp
```

```
#include "CSVReader.h"

vector<CSVLine> CSVReader::read(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    vector<CSVLine> lines;
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    string line = "";

    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        CSVLine csvLine;
        csvLine.parse(line);
        lines.push_back(csvLine);
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do.

First, I would translate the table of features to a [higher-order macro](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/):

```
#define FOREACH_FEATURE(OP)                     \
  OP(1, SampleCodeNumber, int, -1)              \
  OP(2, ClumpThickness, int, -1)                \
  OP(3, UniformityOfCellSize, int, -1)
// Fill in the rest of the table of features here yourself
```

Then I would use this macro to generate a struct with all the features of a patient like this:

```
struct PatientData {
#define DECL_FEATURE(index, name, type, init) type name = init;
  FOREACH_FEATURE(DECL_FEATURE)
#undef DECL_FEATURE

  PatientData() {}
  
  PatientData(CSVLine& src) {
#define READ_FEATURE(index, name, type, init) name = src.getInt(index-1);
    FOREACH_FEATURE(READ_FEATURE)
#undef READ_FEATURE
  }
};
```

Then I would construct a `PatientData` object from a `CSVLine`:

```
CSVLine line = ...;
PatientData patientData(line);
```

Then I would implement the decision tree as nested `if`-statements on the `patientData` object:

```
if (patientData.UniformityOfCellSize <= 2) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

This would get you started but you need to complete and possible extend the `FOREACH_FEATURE` macro and implement the decision tree...

## Nodes and pointers approach

If you don't want to implement your tree like above, ditch the above code and instead do the following. Start by including a few files that we need and implement a `Feature` class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Feature {
  int index1;
  int apply(CSVLine& line) const {return line.getInt(index1-1);}
};
```

and translate the table of features to `Feature` like this:

```
Feature SampleCodeNumber{1};
Feature ClumpThickness{2};
Feature UniformityOfCellSize{3};
// Fill in the rest yourself
```

We are going to use an `std::function<bool(CSVLine)>` to decide for the branch in the tree:

```
typedef std::function<bool(CSVLine&)> BranchCondition;
```

Overloading the comparison operator for a `Feature` and `double` to return a `BranchCondition` lets us neatly express `BranchCondition`s:

```
#define DEF_FEATURE_OP(op) BranchCondition operator op (Feature f, double x) {return [f, x](CSVLine& line) {return f.apply(line) op x;};}
DEF_FEATURE_OP(<)
DEF_FEATURE_OP(<=)
DEF_FEATURE_OP(>)
DEF_FEATURE_OP(>=)
#undef DEF_FEATURE_OP
```

We also need to declare the return value of the classification:

```
enum class Severity {
  Benign, Malign
};
```

As a base class for the decision tree we declare

```
class PatientClassifier {
public:
  virtual Severity classify(CSVLine& p) const = 0;
  virtual ~PatientClassifier() {}
};
```

and implement it for the trivial case of a constant value along with a function `severity` to construct it:

```
class ConstantClassifier : public PatientClassifier {
public:
  ConstantClassifier(Severity v) : _value(v) {}
  Severity classify(CSVLine&) const override {return _value;}
private:
  Severity _value;
};

std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier> severity(Severity v) {
  return std::make_shared<ConstantClassifier>(v);
}
```

and for the branching case along with a function `branch`:

```
class BranchingClassifier : public PatientClassifier {
public:
  BranchingClassifier(
    BranchCondition f,
    const std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier>& onTrue,
    const std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier>& onFalse)
    : _f(f), _onTrue(onTrue), _onFalse(onFalse) {}
  
  Severity classify(CSVLine& p) const override {
    return (_f(p)? _onTrue : _onFalse)->classify(p);
  }
private:
  BranchCondition _f;
  std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier> _onTrue;
  std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier> _onFalse;
};

std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier> branch(
  BranchCondition f,
  const std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier>& onTrue,
  const std::shared_ptr<PatientClassifier>& onFalse) {
  return std::make_shared<BranchingClassifier>(f, onTrue, onFalse);
}
```

and then we just build the tree like

```
  auto decisionTree = branch(
    UniformityOfCellSize <= 2.0,
    severity(Severity::Benign),
    severity(Severity::Malign));

  CSVLine line;
  auto result = decisionTree->classify(line);
```

**Note:** You don't need custom copy constructor and assignment operator for `CSVLine`. And the `getInt` method could be marked as `const`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your tips. I was hoping to get an explanation as to how I would implement node pointers instead of having just massive list of if-else statements. I am thinking I should make a decision node that declares a true and false node and run my data with them to determine which branch to go to next.

I hope this makes sense. I am just not sure how to actually code these nodes to point to the next branch of the tree. If you could help me out on this, I would be super greatful!

Comment: For example, using the data I provided above:

Ive created a node class for each attribute that is used to determine whether the tumor is Benign or Malignant.

class Uniformity_of_Cell_Size_Node : public DecisionNode<CancerDecisionTree::patient_data>
{
public:

Uniformity_of_Cell_Size_Node(DecisionNode* left_node, DecisionNode* right_node)
              : DecisionNode<CancerDecisionTree::patient_data>(t_node, f_node) {}

bool process(CancerDecisionTree::patient_data& data)
{
      if(data.cellSize <= 2)
      {
         return left_node_->process(data);
      }
    etc......

Comment: My problem is that according to the tree provided above, Uniformity of Cell Size has multiple conditions

1. if the cell size is <= 2 then look at Bare Nuclei
2. if the cell size is > 2 then look at Uniformity of Cell Shape
3. if the cell shape is >2 then look at the Cell Size and if that is <= 4 look at Bare Nuclei
4. if the bare nuclei >2 then look at the Clump Thickness and if that is <=6 look at the 
                    Cell Size and if that is <=3 then is Malignant 
                                        BUT
         if the Cell Size is >4 then Malignant

Comment: In my opinion, nested `if` statements are still the simplest solution for such a small decision tree with less code, fewer bugs and faster code. Unless you don't have the specification of the decision tree when you write your program, I think you are *over-engineering* your code if you build the decision tree using *nodes* and *pointers*. And you will still need lots of code to *construct* the decision tree, but the code will be something else than nested `if`s. Why do you prefer a solution based on nodes and pointers?

Comment: for this problem it is required that I used nodes and pointers. I am to declare a root node and then from the data read in from the .csv file I need nodes that point to either situation (to the left or right side of the tree). 

For example, if the Cell Size is <=2 then I should traverse to the left side of the tree.

If the Cell Size is >2 then I should traverse to the right side of the tree.

Comment: @Dylan I see. I extended the answer with a nodes and pointers approach but it is a lot more code. Note by the way that `Cell size <= 2` is the *opposite of* `Cell size > 2`. So if you already tested if `Cell size <= 2` then it redundant to test if `Cell size > 2`.