# Walking through a binary decision tree with data that is stored in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-tree, nodes, decision-tree

I have binary decision tree that will decide on a number of attributes whether or not a tumor in question is benign or malignant. The data of these attributes for each patient in stored in a linked list. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to process the data stored in the linked list through the decision tree to have the expected outcome of wither benign or malignant.

As of now, I have all the code written for the decision tree and the linked list. The linked list is populated with the data that was read in from a .csv file. I have created a header file name ProcessingPatientData.h

In this file I would like to declare a void process_data function that will take the decision tree and the linked list as the parameters and then run the data through the tree to determine the outcomes for each patient.

I would also like to declare other functions but that is not my issue. I am having trouble figuring out how to include my linked list as a parameter

Below you will find my code for the linked list and decision tree as well as what I have so far for the function "process_data".

`

```
#include "CancerLogic.h"
#include "DecisionNode.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "ProcessPatientData.h"

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int clump_thickness;
    int uniformity_of_cell_size;
    int uniformity_of_cell_shape;
    int marginal_adhesion;
    int single_epithelial_cell_size;
    int bare_nuclei;
    int bland_chromatin;
    int normal_nucleoli;
    int mitoses;
    int class_;
}Patients;

void cancer_tree()
{
    // Create the tree
    // Terminal Nodes
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> malignant_node(CancerLogic::malignant);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> benign_node(CancerLogic::benign);

    // Right side (true) nodes
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ma_greater_than_3_r_node(CancerLogic::ma_greater_than_3_r, &malignant_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ct_greater_than_5_r_node(CancerLogic::ct_greater_than_5_r, &malignant_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ma_greater_than_5_r_node(CancerLogic::ma_greater_than_5_r, &malignant_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> csize_greater_than_3_r_node(CancerLogic::csize_greater_than_3_r, &ma_greater_than_5_r_node, &malignant_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ct_greater_than_6_r_node(CancerLogic::ct_greater_than_6_r, &malignant_node, &csize_greater_than_3_r_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> bn_greater_than_2_r_node(CancerLogic::bn_greater_than_2_r, &ct_greater_than_6_r_node, &ma_greater_than_3_r_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> csize_greater_than_4_r_node(CancerLogic::csize_greater_than_4_r, &malignant_node, &bn_greater_than_2_r_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> cshape_greater_than_2_r_node(CancerLogic::cshape_greater_than_2_r, &csize_greater_than_4_r_node, &ct_greater_than_5_r_node);

    // Left side (false) nodes
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ma_greater_than_3_l_node(CancerLogic::ma_greater_than_3_l, &malignant_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> bc_greater_than_2_l_node(CancerLogic::bc_greater_than_2_l, &malignant_node, &ma_greater_than_3_l_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> ct_greater_than_3_l_node(CancerLogic::ct_greater_than_3_l, &bc_greater_than_2_l_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> bn_greater_than_3_l_node(CancerLogic::bn_greater_than_3_l, &ct_greater_than_3_l_node, &benign_node);
    DecisionNode<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data> csize_greater_than_2_node(CancerLogic::csize_greater_than_2, &cshape_greater_than_2_r_node, &bn_greater_than_3_l_node);

    
    process_data<CancerLogic::patient_processing_data>(&csize_greater_than_2_node, );   <----
```

```
class CancerLogic
{
public:
    struct patient_processing_data
    {
        bool csize_greater_than_2_l;
        bool bn_greater_than_3_l;
        bool ct_greater_than_3_l;
        bool bc_greater_than_2_l;
        bool ma_greater_than_3_l;

        bool csize_greater_than_2_r;
        bool cshape_greater_than2_r;
        bool ct_greater_than_5_r;
        bool csize_greater_than_4_r;
        bool bn_greater_than_2_r;
        bool ma_greater_than_3_r;
        bool ct_greater_than_6_r;
        bool csize_greater_than_3_r;
        bool ma_greater_than_5_r;
        bool result;
        std::string result_string;

        patient_processing_data(): csize_greater_than_2_l(false), bn_greater_than_3_l(false),
                                   ct_greater_than_3_l(false), bc_greater_than_2_l(false),
                                   ma_greater_than_3_l(false),
                                   csize_greater_than_2_r(false),
                                   cshape_greater_than2_r(false),
                                   ct_greater_than_5_r(false),
                                   csize_greater_than_4_r(false),
                                   bn_greater_than_2_r(false),
                                   ma_greater_than_3_r(false), ct_greater_than_6_r(false),
                                   csize_greater_than_3_r(false),
                                   ma_greater_than_5_r(false), result(false)
        {
        }
    };

    static bool malignant(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        data.result_string = "Malignant";

        return data.result;
    }

    static bool benign(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = false;
        data.result_string = "Benign";

        return data.result;
    }

    static bool csize_greater_than_4_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ma_greater_than_5_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool csize_greater_than_3_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ct_greater_than_6_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool bn_greater_than_2_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ma_greater_than_3_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool cshape_greater_than_2_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ct_greater_than_5_r(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool csize_greater_than_2(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool bn_greater_than_3_l(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ct_greater_than_3_l(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool bc_greater_than_2_l(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }

    static bool ma_greater_than_3_l(patient_processing_data& data)
    {
        data.result = true;
        return data.result;
    }
};
```

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"


PatientList::PatientList()
{
    head_ = nullptr;
    tail_ = nullptr;
}

void PatientList::insert(int ct, int csize, int cshape, int ma, int bn, int bc)
{
    Node* new_node_ = new Node(ct, csize, cshape, ma, bn, bc);

    if(head_ == nullptr)
    {
        head_ = new_node_;
        tail_ = new_node_;
        return;
    }

    new_node_->previous = tail_;
    tail_->next = new_node_;
    tail_ = new_node_;
}
```

`

```
#pragma once

#include "DecisionNode.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void process_data(DecisionNode<typename T::processing_data>* d_tree, PatientList<typename T::processing_data>& patient_data)
{
    for(auto& data : patient_data)
    {
        d_tree->process(data);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void print_data(const PatientList<typename T::processing_data>& patient_data)
{
    for(const auto& data : patient_data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sorry for all the code, I just want to make sure I have as much info about my problem out there for everyone to try to understand what my problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi :) I am having trouble understanding what your question is exactly

Comment: I don't see any of these "decision nodes" actually making decisions based on the patient data. Presumably running the decision tree would involve providing the root node with the data for one patient. Depending on the outcome of the test will determine whether to follow the left or right branch. You continue doing this, each time passing the patient data to the current node, until you end up on a terminal node. This is fundamentally how decision trees operate. It's weird to completely build one, along with templates, and then scratch your head over how it's used.

Comment: @paddy That is another problem I am having. I am not sure where to implement these checks for the decisions to be as to which branch to take in the tree to eventually reach the terminal node.

Very sorry if this looks weird. I am a first year student and I am still trying to wrap me head around this all. I understand how the tree is used in general but when it comes to coding and figuring out what exactly to provide to traverse the tree with the data is presenting difficulty for me.

Comment: I provided extensive help with this a few days ago... https://stackoverflow.com/a/74568721/1008794

Answer (score 0):

A binary decision tree is quite simple. At each node in the tree, you either have a decision (if it's a leaf node), or you have a junction. To traverse either left or right at a junction requires a classifier.

One example of a classifier is something that examines a specific value in your data and compares it against a value. So, let's take the first junction in your tree (referencing the table in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74568450/)): This states:

> Uniformity of Cell Size <= 2

Then it goes on to choose either one path or another based on whether that test is true or false. That is a classifier.

Rather than attempt to fix your incomplete code, I'm gonna walk you through how I would approach this in C++ myself, step by step. The intention is not to give you code, but to show you *a method* of breaking down the task. If you pay attention, then at some point you'll shout "AHA!", and then go and fix your own program.

### Step 1: Define the data source

Before even thinking about creating a tree, you need to figure out how a classifier might look. And before that, you need some data. I'll mostly copy your structure, with minor changes:

```
struct LabResults
{
    int clump_thickness;
    int uniformity_of_cell_size;
    int uniformity_of_cell_shape;
    int marginal_adhesion;
    int single_epithelial_cell_size;
    int bare_nuclei;
    int bland_chromatin;
    int normal_nucleoli;
    int mitoses;
};

enum class Diagnosis
{
    Unknown,
    Benign,
    Malignant
};

struct Patient
{
    int id;
    LabResults results;
    Diagnosis diagnosis;
};
```

Now we have a structure to hold patient information, with the lab results and diagnosis clearly separated. Although the `Patient` stores a bunch of information, we'll only need `LabResults` to perform classification.

### Step 2: Define a classifier

You can now consider the classifier itself, because you now know it will need to examine a `LabResults` object.

Let's go one step further and make the classifier generic. We can define an abstract class template for this, which will operate on *any* data. That makes it reusable, if you ever want to build decision trees for other stuff:

```
template<class Data>
class Classifier
{
public:
    virtual ~Classifier() = default;
    virtual bool Classify(const Data&) const = 0;
};
```

That's all it needs! We will be able to subclass this to write specific classifiers, but the main interface will be via a `Classifier<LabResults>*` value, on which we'll be calling the polymorphic `Classify` method. That method accepts a reference to one patient's `LabResults` data.

So now, let's build a very useful classifier. This is gonna be the only one you need for this entire decision tree! Again, everything's kept generic. Let's see it first, then I'll explain:

```
// Classifier to perform binary comparison
template<class Data, class Value, class Compare>
class BinaryClassifier : public Classifier<Data>
{
public:
    BinaryClassifier(Value LabResults::*member, Value value)
        : mMember(member)
        , mValue(value)
    { }

    bool Classify(const Data& data) const override
    {
        return Compare()(data.*mMember, mValue);
    }

private:
    Value LabResults::*mMember;
    Value mValue;
};
```

The constructor for this classifier uses pointer-to-member semantics to target any member of the `Data` type. It also templates the data type of that member (via `Value`) although in your case that's always gonna be `int`. And finally it provides a functor `Compare` which provides a way to specify what kind of comparison operation to do. Your decision tree happens to only need `<=`, which is conveniently available as `std::less_equal`.

If you're not familiar with *pointer-to-member*, search it up. Same goes for *functors*. You'll see both of these used in the `Classify` method. Neat!

And so, we can now create a classifier. Let's do one for `clump_thickness <= 5`:

```
using LessEqualClassifier = BinaryClassifier<LabResults, int, std::less_equal<int>>;
LessEqualClassifier classifier(&LabResults::clump_thickness, 5);
```

### Step 3: Test the classifier!

That's enough coding... This is the perfect time to stop and make sure the classifier actually works. Let's quickly chuck in some of your data and run the classifier on it:

```
int main()
{
    using LessEqualClassifier = BinaryClassifier<LabResults, int, std::less_equal<int>>;

    LessEqualClassifier classifier(&LabResults::clump_thickness, 5);

    Patient patients[] {
        { 1000025, { 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1 } },
        { 1002945, { 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 3, 2, 1 } },
        { 1015425, { 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1 } },
        { 1016277, { 6, 8, 8, 1, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1 } },
        { 1017023, { 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1 } },
        { 1017122, { 8, 10, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 7, 1 } },
    };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    for (auto& p : patients)
    {
        std::cout << "Patient " << p.id << ": ";
        std::cout << classifier.Classify(p.results) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Patient 1000025: true
Patient 1002945: true
Patient 1015425: true
Patient 1016277: false
Patient 1017023: true
Patient 1017122: false
```

And yes, indeed you can see that this is operating as expected. We've hardly written any code, yet already we have a generic classifier that can work on any member of LabResults. Go ahead and try it with other members and values.

### Step 4: Define a decision tree

With a working classifier, we can now focus on the decision tree itself. As I said at the beginning, a node in the tree is either a final decision or a junction. Let's begin with a class for the tree:

```
template <class Data, class Result>
class DecisionTree
{
public:
    class Node;

    DecisionTree(Node&& definition)
        : mRoot(std::move(definition))
    { }

    Result Run(const Data& data) const
    {
        return mRoot.Run(data);
    }

private:
    Node mRoot;
};
```

This tree simply has a root node, and it can call the `Run` method on that node (which we'll define shortly). This will execute the decision tree and return the outcome. The tree for your data will be of type `DecisionTree<LabResults, Diagnosis>`. So that means you'll be passing in the `LabResults` for a patient, and getting a `Diagnosis` value back out.

Let's now define the node class itself:

```
template <class Data, class Result>
class DecisionTree<Data, Result>::Node
{
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Classifier<Data>> ClassifierPtr;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> NodePtr;

    Node(const Result& result)
        : mResult(result)
    { }

    Node(ClassifierPtr&& classifier, Node&& trueCase, Node&& falseCase)
        : mResult()
        , mClassifier(std::move(classifier))
        , mTrueCase(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(trueCase)))
        , mFalseCase(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(falseCase)))
    { }

private:
    friend class DecisionTree;
    Result Run(const Data& data) const
    {
        return mClassifier
            ? (mClassifier->Classify(data) ? mTrueCase : mFalseCase)->Run(data)
            : mResult;
    }

private:
    Result          mResult;
    ClassifierPtr   mClassifier;
    NodePtr         mTrueCase;
    NodePtr         mFalseCase;
};
```

You can see that there are two possible ways to construct `DecisionTree::Node`. You can either specify a `Result` or you can provide a pointer to a classifier along with a tree node representing the two possible outcomes of that classifier. If the classifier is null, then the node is a leaf, otherwise it is a junction.

The `Run` method will execute the classifier if one exists, and depending on the outcome it will then recursively run the appropriate subtree. If there is no classifier, the `Result` stored at that node is returned.

And that is pretty much the entire system. By now, you'll be itching to actually start building out your tree, so let's do that.

### Step 5: Construct a tree

The nice thing about this design is we can build the tree in one hit, nesting the two different node constructors to define the decision structure. But you don't have to. You might wish to define it in a file somewhere, parse that, and build the tree dynamically. It's up to you.

As always though, start with something simple. You wanna be testing code in stages as you go, as early as possible.

First, let's make a cleaner way to create our classifiers. Because notice that it needs to be a `std::unique_ptr`, so we'll be writing `std::make_unique<LessEqualClassifier>(...)` everywhere. Or without that alias: `std::make_unique<BinaryClassifier<LabResults, int, std::less_equal<int>>(...)`... ewww!

How about this simple function template:

```
// Classifier factories make life easier!
template <class Data, class Value>
std::unique_ptr<Classifier<Data>> LessEqual(Value Data::*member, Value value)
{
    typedef BinaryClassifier<LabResults, Value, std::less_equal<Value>> LessEqualType;
    return std::make_unique<LessEqualType>(member, value);
}
```

Now let's build out the left branch in the tree, leaving the right branch to diagnose as Unknown. That just gets things off the ground so there's something to test:

```
DecisionTree<LabResults, Diagnosis> cancerDiagnoser({
    LessEqual(&LabResults::uniformity_of_cell_size, 2),{
        // uniformity_of_cell_size <= 2
        LessEqual(&LabResults::bare_nuclei, 3),{
            Diagnosis::Benign
        },{
            LessEqual(&LabResults::clump_thickness, 3),{
                Diagnosis::Benign
            },{
                LessEqual(&LabResults::bland_chromatin, 2),{
                    LessEqual(&LabResults::marginal_adhesion, 3),{
                        Diagnosis::Malignant
                    },{
                        Diagnosis::Benign
                    }
                },{
                    Diagnosis::Malignant
                }
            }
        }
    },{
        // uniformity_of_cell_size > 2

        //// TODO !!!
        Diagnosis::Unknown
    }
});
```

### Step 6: Test the tree!

We'll want to be able to output the diagnosis. A clean way to do that is to define a stream output operator for it. That way, you can just send a `Diagnosis` value directly to `std::cout` and have it output something friendly:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Diagnosis& d)
{
    std::array<const char*, 3> names{ "Unknown", "Benign", "Malignant" };
    return s << names.at(static_cast<int>(d));
}
```

Now update the testing loop from earlier. The only change required is to run the decision tree, store the result and output it:

```
for (auto& p : patients)
{
    p.diagnosis = cancerDiagnoser.Run(p.results);
    std::cout << "Patient " << p.id << ": " << p.diagnosis << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Patient 1000025: Benign
Patient 1002945: Unknown
Patient 1015425: Benign
Patient 1016277: Unknown
Patient 1017023: Benign
Patient 1017122: Unknown
```

Looks like we didn't get any Malignant diagnoses with this data. Try it with data that IS malignant on that side of the tree. You can just invent something. In fact, you can craft some bogus data to test the tree:

```
Patient unitTests[] {
    { 1001, { 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0 }, Diagnosis::Benign },
    { 1002, { 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0 }, Diagnosis::Benign },
    { 1003, { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 }, Diagnosis::Malignant },
    { 1004, { 4, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 }, Diagnosis::Benign },
    { 1005, { 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 }, Diagnosis::Malignant },
};

for (auto& p : unitTests)
{
    auto diagnosis = cancerDiagnoser.Run(p.results);
    bool pass = diagnosis == p.diagnosis;
    std::cout << "Patient " << p.id << ": " << diagnosis;
    std::cout << " - " << (pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Patient 1001: Benign - PASS
Patient 1002: Benign - PASS
Patient 1003: Malignant - PASS
Patient 1004: Benign - PASS
Patient 1005: Malignant - PASS
```

As you build out the rest of the tree, you'll wanna include more tests to make sure the logic is right. Cos you REALLY don't wanna be misdiagnosing cancers due to a software bug!!!

### Summary

By now, you have all the tools you need. This is intentionally unfinished code. If this is for school work and you decide to copy it outright and finish it, I think people will suspect it's not yours!

Instead, what you should do is study what's actually happening and adapt concepts into your own program. If you take away only one thing from this answer, I hope it's the *approach* of building up a program from nothing in a series of small, logical, *testable* steps.